# Linker for Clang

Tags: c++, linker, g++, clang

Which linker do I use for Clang?

If I use Clang or [GNU linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29#GNU_linker) (`ld`) as the linker, I get massive amounts of errors as if I didn't link with the standard library.

```
g++ $(OBJS) -o $(BINDIR)/obtap
```

It seems I have to use g++ in order to link my Clang objects.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was running 'clang' instead of 'clang++', meaning it didn't link the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to use llvm's link editor. I will avoid getting into the technical details, but, in short, you will need to have a typical Unix link editor available to use Clang at this time (read: GNU ld or Sun ld). Even llvm-ld uses the underlying platform's linker to link native binaries.

Answer (score 4):

Follow-up: it's now 2016, and [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) has made some steady progress on their own linker.  It's called "lld", and [the website is here](http://lld.llvm.org/). It works fine to create i386 and x86_64 binaries, while work is ongoing to target other systems.

This should remove the dependency on GNU tools for [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) systems, once it is considered stable enough.