# C++ - Clang linker problem and getting debug information

Tags: c++, linker-errors, llvm, clang

I want to do the analysis of debug information of C++ code.
As I understand, Clang should be able to handle C++.

I tried `clang myFile.cpp`.
But I get

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang error: linker command failed due to signal 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

After setting the path for *llvm-ld*, it partially works. I mean, if I perform

```
clang C:myFile.cpp -S -emit-llvm -o -
```

it outputs some information. But it still fails for `clang myFile.cpp` with error

```
clang version 2.9 (tags/RELEASE_29/final)
Target: i686-pc-win32
Thread model: posix
 "C:/FrontEnd/llvm/bin/Debug/clang.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-win32 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name BinarySearch_Kernels.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir C:/FrontEnd/l
lvm/bin/Debug\..\lib\clang\2.9 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 280 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fms-extensions -fmsc-version=1300 -fgnu-runtime -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o C:/Users/ilipov/AppData/Local/Temp/cc-563130.o -x c++ C:\clang\BinarySearch_Kernels
.cpp
clang -cc1 version 2.9 based upon llvm 2.9 hosted on i686-pc-win32
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
  #include "..." search starts here:
  #include <...> search starts here:
 C:/FrontEnd/llvm/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/2.9/include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\\include
End of search list.
 "link.exe" -out:a.out -defaultlib:libcmt -nologo C:/Users/ilipov/AppData/Local/Temp/cc-563130.o
clang: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any case, I want to get **as full debug information as possible**

For example, for

```cpp
class stamBase
{
public:
    int get1(){return 2;};
    int get0(){return 0;}
};
class stamDer : public stamBase
{
public:
    int get1(){return 1;}
};
void func()
{
    stamDer d;
    int x = d.get1();
}
```

I get

```
target datalayout = "e-p:32:32:32-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-f80:128:128-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-f80:32:32-n8:16:32"
target triple = "i686-pc-win32"
%class.stamDer = type { i8 }
define void @_Z4funcv() {
entry:
  %d = alloca %class.stamDer, align 1
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  %call = call i32 @_ZN7stamDer4get1Ev(%class.stamDer* %d)
  store i32 %call, i32* %x, align 4
  ret void
}
define linkonce_odr i32 @_ZN7stamDer4get1Ev(%class.stamDer* %this) nounwind align 2 {
entry:
  %this.addr = alloca %class.stamDer*, align 4
  store %class.stamDer* %this, %class.stamDer** %this.addr, align 4
  %this1 = load %class.stamDer** %this.addr
  ret i32 1
}
```

From my investigation of Clang debug information code, I thought that I should get the information for stamBase too!

How can I run Clang correctly for accepting full debug information and preventing Clang errors?

Comment: You need a linker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925409/linker-for-clang (Apparently I am not allowed to write this as an answer. Stupid site.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to install a linker. [GNU ld](http://www.gnu.org/s/binutils/) will be fine; you should be able to install it via your package manager.

There also is an [LLVM linker](http://llvm.org/cmds/llvm-ld.html). It is less popular, but it would run out of the box with Clang once installed (just add it to the `PATH` a rerun `clang`).

Comment: I use clang with llvm - is there anothe option for the linker?

Comment: @Yakov: either ld or gold, both should work. ld has the advantage of being standard and cross-platform.

Comment: Suppose I installed llvm-ld or GNU-ld  either-ld.how should I run clang now with my cpp file?

Comment: I have llvm-ld exe. It was added to path.But I still get the same error.

Comment: @Yakov: You should run it with `-v` to have more details about your error, and post relevant information here.

Comment: -cc1 -triple i686-pc-win32 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-n
lvm/bin/Debug\..\lib\clang\2.9 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 280 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fms-extensions.cpp
clang -cc1 version 2.9 based upon llvm 2.9 hosted on i686-pc-win32
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/llvm/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/2.9/include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\\includ

Comment: This has been stripped by the comment system, can you put that into the question ?

Comment: llvm-ld is not a general purpose linker and will not solve this problem. You need the developer tools for your platform installed in order to get binaries linked.