# How do I tell CMake to use Clang on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, build, cmake, clang

I have a C++ project that builds using CMake. I usually build on OSX but now I am trying to get a Windows version working too. I would like to use Clang on Windows for compatibility reasons.

I installed the pre-compiled Clang 3.8 binary from LLVM:

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe
```

It is also installed on my PATH:

```
>clang++
clang++.exe: error: no input files
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I tell CMake to use `clang++` when I call `cmake --build`?
2. How can I check before building which compiler CMake is configured with?

Comment: There's the `toolchain.txt` file, lookup for this one in the docs.

Comment: On ubuntu, I use  CC='g++ -m64' when I invoke the g++ compiler via Make (Make has $(CC) in it)  I use CC="clang++ -m64' to invoke clang++.  (I do not use CMake nor Windows)

Comment: What's wrong with using `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/path/to/clang++`?

Comment: @usr1234567 It's platform-dependent, i.e. can't use a single, portable recipe like `cmake .. && cmake --build .`, but have to except for windos.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You also need - in addition to the Clang compilers itself - an build/link environment for Windows.

The latest CMake 3.6 builds do have several integrated supported Clang build environments on Windows (e.g. Visual Studio, Cygwin; see [Release Notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/release/3.6.html)).

I've just run a successful test with

- [LLVM-3.9.0-r273898-win32.exe](http://llvm.org/pre-releases/win-snapshots/LLVM-3.9.0-r273898-win32.exe) from http://llvm.org/builds/
- [cmake-3.6.0-rc4-win64-x64.msi](https://cmake.org/files/v3.6/cmake-3.6.0-rc4-win64-x64.msi) from https://cmake.org/download/
- Microsoft VS2015 Community Edition Version 14.0.23107.0

All installed to their standard paths with their `bin` directories in the global `PATH` environment.

The part you need to know is setting the right toolset with the CMake **`-T"LLVM-vs2014"`** command line option. During the configuration process CMake will let you know which compiler it has found/taken.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(HelloWorld)

file(
    WRITE main.cpp 
        "#include <iostream>\n"
        "int main() { std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl; return 0; }"
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

**Windows Console**

```
...> mkdir VS2015
...> cd VS2015
...\VS2015> cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015" -T"LLVM-vs2014" ..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.9.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.9.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: .../VS2015
...\VS2015> cmake --build . 
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 14.0.23107.0
[...]
...\VS2015> Debug\HelloWorld.exe
Hello World!
```

**Installation Hints**

Please note that I have added LLVM to my search paths during setup:

[image: LLVM Installation with Add to PATH]

And you can crosscheck the available "Platform Toolsets" in any VS project's property page:

[image: VS Project Properties - Platform Toolsets]

**References**

- [What is the -D define to tell Cmake where to find nmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106848/what-is-the-d-define-to-tell-cmake-where-to-find-nmake)
- [Linker for Clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925409/linker-for-clang)
- [Switching between GCC and Clang/LLVM using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake)

Comment: Thank you! The bit I was missing was `-T"LLVM-vs2014"`

Comment: awfully confusing. CMake should consider changing -G to MSBuild because that's what it's outputing, and suboptions to set the actual compiler toolchain

Comment: Weird. CMake still chooses the default `cl.exe` on my machine when doing this with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, CMake 3.7.1 and LLVM/Clang 3.9.1: `The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1`.

Comment: @FlorianWolters The difference could be that I have `clang` in my search paths. If you call `clang` directly from your command line, does it find the compiler and is showing `clang.exe: error: no input files`?

Comment: @Florian: `clang` is in the `PATH`. I have been able to narrow the problem: I haven't installed the `LLVM-3.9.1-win32.exe`, but extracted it via 7-Zip and executed `tools\msbuild\install.bat` manually. That does not work and the default MSVC compiler `cl`is used. When installing it, it works as described. Now I have to find out, why it does not work for my portable solution.

Comment: (Almost)portable solution if not running the LLVM installer: Replace the string `<LLVMInstallDir>$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\LLVM\LLVM)</LLVMInstallDir>` in all `.props` files below the dir `tools\msbuild` with the string `<LLVMInstallDir>$(LLVM_ROOT)</LLVMInstallDir>` and make sure the env variable `LLVM_ROOT` points to the dir of the "portable" installation, e.g. `C:\llvm-3.9.1-x86`.
*Problem:* Admin privileges are required to "install" the LLVM toolsets for *MSBuild*. If someone knows how-to use toolsets with *MSBuild* that are not stored in the default dir, please let me know.

Comment: If someone struggles using the CMake-GUI app, just pass `LLVM-vs2014` in the input field for the toolset (-T parameter) there, and not `-T"LLVM-vs2014"`.

Comment: A hint for those using the LLVM installer: install Visual Studio before LLVM. The LLVM installer only installs the toolset for already installed Visual Studio versions (for obvious reasons). Otherwise reinstalling LLVM after installing a new version of Visual Studio helps.

Comment: Future readers, beware. Using CMake 3.9.1 and clang 4.0.1, CMAKE_C_FLAGS gets set to /DWIN32 -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -D_WINDOWS -Wall - and clang-cl complains about the unknown compiler flags. -- but it works fine with the mentioned cmake release.

Answer (score 26):

As an update for **Visual Studio 2019 and 2022**, you can install the clang-cl toolchain via the *Visual Studio Installer* and use this to generate a `.sln` file:

```
> mkdir build && cd build
> cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T ClangCL -A x64
```

or

```
> mkdir build && cd build
> cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T ClangCL -A x64
```

However a much better workflow is to simply [open the folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170) containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file directly in VS and it will recognise it as a CMake project and provide the ability to set the compiler etc. directly.

The only drawback I could find to this approach is that the Visual Studio Graphics Debugger workflow doesn't work with it, which will affect you if you are developing with DirectX etc.

Comment: Thank you for the command, just wanted to inform that now you can use the debugger too.

Comment: @AlexG.G. The Visual Studio Graphics Debugger?

Comment: Nvm I had understood the ui to debug but you mean the tools to debug graphics right?

Comment: In VS 2022 I'm getting a CMake error: `The CXX compiler identification is unknown CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.` when using `ClangCL` toolset. Any idea what could be wrong? I have installed Clang tools via VS installer.

Comment: @szx I'm not certain, no.  What happens if you open the folder in VS2022 and then play with the cmake settings to ensure the correct compiler is being used?

Answer (score 13):

Follow these instructions:

Install choco if you don't have it: https://chocolatey.org/install

```
choco install ninja -y
choco install cmake -y
choco install llvm -y
```

Reset your shell so environment variables are set properly (you can check if bin folders for each are added to your Path).

## Using Ninja

### From PowerShell

```
$env:CC="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe"
$env:CXX="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe"
cmake -S ./ -B ./build -G "Ninja-Multi-Config"
cmake --build ./build --config Release
```

### From GUI

Go to your project and run:

```
cmake-gui .
```

From the upper menu select `Tools/Configure` and follow these settings:

Choose "Ninja Multi-Config" and Specify native compilers:

[image: ninja]

Give the path to the compilers:
[image: compilers]

Finally, run

```
cmake --build ./build --config Release
```

## Using Visual Studio

### From PowerShell

```
cmake -S ./ -B ./build
cmake --build ./build --config Release
```

#### From GUI

In some folder install llvm-utils:

```
git clone https://github.com/zufuliu/llvm-utils.git
cd llvm-utils/VS2017
.\install.bat
```

Go to your project and run:

```
cmake-gui .
```

From the upper menu select `Tools/Configure` and follow these settings:

Choose Visual Studio 2019 and 2nd option (specify native compilers). Set
`LLVM_v142` for Visual Studio 2019 and above. See [here for older versions](https://github.com/zufuliu/llvm-utils#llvm-for-visual-studio-2017-and-2019) for others.
[image: visual_studio]

Give the path to the compilers:
[image: compilers]

Finally, run

```
cmake --build ./build --config Release
```