# CMake building for Windows (clang-cl) using Ninja Generator

Tags: cmake, ninja, clang-cl

I am trying to build a simple application on a Windows machine using CMake as the main build tool. Once CMake is invoked on the project the is an error on configuration phase:

```
> cmake -H. -G Ninja -Bbuild -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe"

-- The C compiler identification is Clang 7.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 7.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe --broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompile
r.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/mak/Desktop/cmake-test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"C:/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/ninja.exe" "cmTC_f5485"
    [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_f5485.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_f5485.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_f5485.exe
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_f5485.dir --manifests  -- CMAKE_LINKER-NOTFOUND  /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_f5485.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_f5485.exe /implib:cmTC_f5485.lib /pdb:cmTC_f5485.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /foCMakeFiles\cmTC_f5485.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_f5485.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the given file
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

I read a lot through the web but my problem was not solved by any proposed solution. What I found so far is a simmilar but maybe outdated [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553436/building-with-cmake-ninja-and-clang-on-windows) to the same problem which did not work for me, because Ninja was not able to build the executable:

```
> ninja all
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/main.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe     -MD -MT CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\minimal.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/main.cpp.obj -c ../main.cpp
clang-cl.exe: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-MF' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang-cl.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/main.cpp.obj'
clang-cl.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles\minimal.dir\main.cpp.obj.d'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Before this error CMake configured properly except that all compilers ABI info detection failed - but CMake resumed without error. There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585874/building-c-project-on-windows-with-cmake-clang-and-ninja) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237300/clang-and-cmake-on-windows) questions out there which did not help either.

The official [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl) states it is quite simple but in fact it is not.

**So:** How do I build a *simple* C++ project using CMake with the Ninja generator and Clang as the compiler? I try to avoid the installation of Visual Studio but it would be great if generated binaries are compatible with MSVC build binaries.

**Versions:**

- CMake 3.12.2
- Ninja 1.8.2
- Clang 7.0.0

---

**Example:** Here is the minial example which I am working with:

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(minimal)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming "Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden" is something like "The system cannot find the path specified", the error is about missed `rc` utility. Also, `CMAKE_LINKER-NOTFOUND` means that CMake has been failed to detect the linker.

Comment: You are totally correct. (Sorry for missing this translation.) I provided both, *CMAKE_LINKER* and *CMAKE_RC_COMPILER* besides all other definitions but it did not work either. The output is pretty the same.

Comment: Could you confirm that you are configuring the project from within a visual studio command line terminal ?

Comment: I do not use nor intend to use any Visual Studio tools. While rereading the documentation one might come to the conclusion that this is a kind of requirement. Can you confirm this? The part using the Ninja generator does not say that directly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I noticed when manually setting `CMAKE_LINKER` this variable is set to `CMAKE_LINKER-NOTFOUND` once I run the configuration (which failes because of this). How to set the linker correctly?

Comment: CMake itself has no specific variable for set the linker, you need to define the whole linking rule ([CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_EXECUTABLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html) for executable, `CMAKE_<LANG>_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY` for shared library, `CMAKE_<LANG>_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE` for module library). May be, some compiler detection scripts take a hint about the linker, but I am unaware of that. Actually, now I am not sure that `CMAKE_LINKER-NOTFOUND` signal about the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile with **clang-cl**, it is necessary to run **cmake** with MSVC environment loaded (use *vcvarsall.bat*). Otherwise it tries to use GCC compatibility options.
It is enough to install just the [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022).